# Select Pane with C-<number> in tmux

Tags: tmux

In `tmux`, the default behavior for processing `C-b 0` is to jump to window 0. I would like `C-b C-0` to jump to pane 0 in the current window. My attempts at adding,

```
bind-key C-0 select-pane -t 0
```

to my `.tmux.conf` have failed. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: do you have one line in your `tmux.conf`: `set -g base-index 1` or `set -g pane-base-index 1`? if yes, your window/pane is 1 based.

Comment: I do, but the statement holds for all numbers other than 0.

Answer (score 77):

Not exactly the way you are looking for, but I doubt you have a reason not to love the following:

1. `display-panes` or the likes (`<prefix> + q` by default),
2. enter the number of the pane you are switching to.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. But the time of pane number showing is too short, Can I set the time value??

Comment: I got it: put "set display-panes-time 2000  #2s" in .tmux.conf

Comment: Do you know how to start this pane numbering from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @phani `set -g pane-base-index 1`

Comment: I would love this feature even more if instead of numbers it would output letters for each panel, since they are much easier to type and much closer to the keyboard's home row.

Answer (score 5):

You need to modify your terminal so that tmux can recognise control+digit keystrokes correctly.
(*source*: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96884/using-ctrl0-9-to-cycle-between-windows-using-tmux)

If you are using iTerm2, for example, then:

1. go to `Preferences > Profiles > Keys` and click `+`
2. input <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> as the *keyboard shortcut*
3. select `Send Escape Sequence` from the *action* drop-down menu
4. input `Esc+[27;5;48~` in the *characters to send* textbox
5. click OK, then restart iTerm

Then, finally add to your `.tmux.conf` the following:

```
bind-key C-0 select-pane -t 0
```

restart tmux (make sure to close all sessions with`tmux kill-session`).  You should now be able to select pane number 0.
To get the other 9 keys to work, repeat the above 5 steps with the appropriate escape sequences. They can be found in the link provided.